# Subscription payment must be up and running for SCA

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

That's how I need to have subscription payment up and running to SCA.

I have spent time reading all the links through etc but I don't really think I can get it up and running as it is shown on the link here:

[3D Secure 2 flow](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#example-of-a-3d-secure-2-flow)

Where the problem lies is with image 2 + 3, none of what is shown on the link happens.

That's how I used the first card that is here on the site. ([CARD HERE](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#three-ds-cards))

**Also** : *4000-0000-0000-3220 - 3D Secure 2 authentication must be completed on all transactions. Use this card to test that your integration is ready to support Strong Customer Authentication requirements in Europe.*

Code here:

```
var api = Settings.Stripe.SecretKey_SK;
                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = api;

                // Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
                // Get the payment token submitted by the form:
                var token = model.Source; // Using ASP.

                var optionsProduct = new ProductCreateOptions
                {
                    Name = "Medlemskab " + companies.Name,
                    Type = "service",
                };
                var serviceProduct = new ProductService();
                Product product = serviceProduct.Create(optionsProduct);

                var optionsPlan = new PlanCreateOptions
                {
                    Currency = "dkk",
                    Interval = Interval,
                    Nickname = "Medlemskab - OrderId: " + OrderId + " InterVal: " + Interval + " Name: " + companies.Name,
                    Amount = amount,
                    Product = product.Id,
                    IntervalCount = getPricInfo.Months,

                };
                var servicePlan = new PlanService();
                Plan plan = servicePlan.Create(optionsPlan);


                var options = new SessionCreateOptions
                {
                    SuccessUrl = "https://www.xx.com/Members/Success",
                    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "card",
                    },
                    SubscriptionData = new SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
                    {
                        Items = new List<SessionSubscriptionDataItemOptions>
                        {
                            new SessionSubscriptionDataItemOptions
                            {
                                PlanId = plan.Id
                            },
                        },
                    },
                };
                var service = new SessionService();
                Session session = service.Create(options);


                //opret kunden i Stripe Systemet.
                var createCustomerStripe = new CustomerCreateOptions
                {
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Description = "Kunde for " + companiesName + " - Email: " + model.Email,
                    Source = token,

                };

                var addService = new CustomerService();
                Customer customer = await addService.CreateAsync(createCustomerStripe);

                //Tilføj customerId her til for, at kunne få det til, at passe sammen.
                var items = new List<SubscriptionItemOption>
                {
                    new SubscriptionItemOption
                    {
                        PlanId = plan.Id
                    }
                };

                var createSubscruption = new SubscriptionCreateOptions
                {
                    CustomerId = customer.Id,
                    Items = items
                };
                createSubscruption.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent");

                var Addservice = new SubscriptionService();
                Subscription subscription = Addservice.Create(createSubscruption);
```

It gets created ie things in logs at Stripe:
[See logs here to Stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXYCB.png)

**So my question is just**: How do I get it resolved so that I will be able to have 3D Secure in relation to SCA so I'm ready there :) and at the same time how can it be that it does not bother at all to be 3D Secure approved right now. Is it because I'm missing some specific place in the code for it to work?